# Add a column if value is null

Tags: mysql

I would like to add a column to a result set based on whether a field `field_value` in the table is `NULL`.

Here is my query that works:

```sql
SELECT field_id, (
   SELECT field_value
   FROM employee_field_info
   WHERE employee_id = '1'
   AND field_id = persona_fields.field_id
) AS field_value, ( 
   SELECT field
   FROM FIELDS WHERE id = persona_fields.field_id
) AS field_name
FROM persona_fields
WHERE persona_id = '1'
```

What i want to be able to do is to add a tinyint (for a bool) column if the `field_value` is `NULL`.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT field_id, (
   SELECT field_value
   FROM employee_field_info
   WHERE employee_id = '1'
   AND field_id = persona_fields.field_id
) AS field_value, ( 
   SELECT field
   FROM FIELDS WHERE id = persona_fields.field_id
) AS field_name,
IF(field_value IS NULL, "0","1") AS value_bool
FROM persona_fields
WHERE persona_id = '1'
```

But that just comes up with the "Unknown column 'field_value' in 'field list.'
Is there anyway i can accomplish what I'm trying to do, or am I pretty much out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference columns in the parent `SELECT` from a sub-select. The sub-select is basically run in isolation. What you need to do is re-write this as a `JOIN`. Your query is quite convoluted and hard to follow, and I think incomplete, so I can only approximate a solution.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT field_id,
  employee_field_info.field_value,
  IF(employee_field_info.field_value IS NULL, "0","1") AS value_bool
  FROM persona_fields
  LEFT JOIN employee_field_info ON employee_field_info.field_id=persona_fields.field_id
  WHERE employee_id=1
```

Comment: That's essentially what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here.. you are trying to get a field which is not available in the **field_list**. sometimes you will get this error because you are using a DB development tool in which the field is modified not yet committed.

about your query: It is better avoid such sub queries for such simple result a simple join would be very fine.